# Entity Framework: Add-Migration is removing the nullable:false (allowing null)

Tags: entity-framework

The migration believes email should now be nullable, and I can't see where it's coming up with this idea. The database before the migration is NOT NULL. Running `Add-Migration` produces the code changes below, where Email is now marked nullable; however, the [Required] attribute is present on the string and this code has been untouched for sometime.  What are some other side-effects that could be causing this behavior? (Target is SQL server)

(1) Unchanged Model:

```cs
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
   // .. snip...

   [JsonProperty("email"), Required, Display(Name = "Email")]
   public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

(2)
`Add-Migration ExampleMigration`

(3) Output migration:

```cs
public partial class ExampleMigration : DbMigration
{
  public override void Up()
  {
    AlterColumn("dbo.UserProfile", "Email", c => c.String());
  }
  
  public override void Down()
  {
    AlterColumn("dbo.UserProfile", "Email", c => c.String(nullable: false));
  }
}
```

Comparing resx migration schemas shows the same result, where the latest migration removes `Nullable="false"`.

Before

```xml
<Property Name="Email" Type="String" MaxLength="Max" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" Nullable="false" />
```

After

```xml
<Property Name="Email" Type="String" MaxLength="Max" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
```

Comment: Does your project reference any .NET Standard libraries, or have a reference to the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` NuGet package? If so, it might be related to [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/issues/1499).

Answer (score 0):

To work around this issue, I ran the migration, removed the incorrect lines from up/down, did a file compare against the prior and current migration decompressed 'target' value in the resx, took the changes I wanted, and recompressed the result and jammed it back in the resx.

Not ideal. Not recommended.